# Does Symfony3 / Doctrine open one MySQL connection per visitor?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have developped this website with `Symfony3` and `Doctrine`. I have one major concern about performance with MySQL and more specifically the number of simultaneous open connexions.

For the moment, one to five users are online on the website. What happens if, let's say, `1,500` users connect within one minute? Does Symfony3 or Doctrine handle this kind of situations? How can I be sure the website doesn't go down providing me with the `Too many connections` MySQL error?

And if I go up to `5,000`? And `10,000`? The server has `4GB` of RAM and a `2.40Ghz` mono-core processor but I wouldn't worry about the hardware as I'm more concerned about MySQL.

These situations already happened in the past but I was running the website with Wordpress and W3 Total Cache plugin. Should I consider using a cache manager such as `memcached` or else?

In short, I'm concerned about the website becoming unavailable in case of sudden high trafic (and thought of the MysQL `Too many connections` error in first but I might be missing something even more important).

Thanks for lightening me out on this one as I'm not fully aware about performance issues with Symfony.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it does open one connection per visitor. Regardless of whether it does or not however neither Symfony or Doctrine has a magic bullet to handle every load/connection scenario.

Why don't you use a load testing tool (there are many) and see how it actually pans out? In my experience predicting a bottleneck is useless, as they will always crop up where you least expect it.

For example, the MySQL connection limit is only one part of the optimisation puzzle. It's no good just worrying about connection limits, you need to respond to web requests as quickly and efficiently as possible to free up MySQL connection resources (and other resources your app is using). So if your server is slow you will run out of connections (or some other resource) almost immediately under significant load, regardless of MySQL connection limits.

That said, those server specifications seem a little low for 5-10k users per minute. I wouldn't expect a machine like that to handle that kind of load without some serious optimisation/caching/etc.

The [symfony performance page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html) is a good starter, and there is also a good [article on caching](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html) - there's a [ton of available material](https://www.google.com/#q=symfony%20performance%20optimization&rct=j) on the subject. Good luck! :)

Comment: Following your recommendations, I've upgraded to PHP7.0 and used OpCache. Do you think this will be enough?

Comment: @D4V1D - I can't answer that for you. You know your site's requirements best so you need to test with an appropriate load testing tool. If it doesn't meet requirements, more optimisation is needed.

Comment: Indeed, I've just ran a few tests with [HTTPerf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf). I simulated 5,000 HTTP requests, here are the results: `Connection rate: 8.9 conn/s (112.0 ms/conn, <=1 concurrent connections)` / `Connection time [ms]: min 96.4 avg 112.0 max 324.7 median 111.5 stddev 6.8` / `Reply status: 1xx=0 2xx=5000 3xx=0 4xx=0 5xx=0`. The tests took `560.190 s` to accomplish. I guess these are some good news.

Answer (score 1):

If you use php-fpm it depends on pm.max_children in fpm/pool.d/www.conf.

**pm.max_children** refers to the maximum number of concurrent PHP-FPM processes allowed to exist in such a pool. If the volume of incoming requests requires the creation of more PHP-FPM processes than the number allowed by the max_children limit, those additional requests are backlogged in a queue to await service.

So when pm.max_children > max_connections (my.cnf) and active users > max_connections you will get "Too many connections".